# saving changed values to a new object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

I have an array of objects and I used v-for to display them. However I want to change few of those items from the array and save only the changed objects in a new object.

template

```
<b-card-group columns>
    <b-card-body>
      <b-form-group v-for="(value, index) in anotherItems" :key="index" class="form-group">
        <b-form-input v-model="item[value]" class="form-control"></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
    </b-card-body>
  </b-card>
</b-card-group>
```

Methods:

```
data(){
   return{
     changedValueArray: []
},
methods: {
  justAnotherFunction() {
    const newData = this.items.map((item) => {
      const newItem = {};
      newItem.item_id = item.id;
      return newItem;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The values in "anotherItems" is mapped to the val in items?

Comment: yeah right @FaranAli

Comment: in the solution below, how do you think should I use the changedValueArray?

Comment: Yes you can use it

Comment: can you show me in another answer as in how to use it? @FaranAli

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to events on your component, so that you trigger a function everytime your value is updated:

```
<b-form-input
  v-model="item[value + '_change']"
  class="form-control"
  @changge="(newValue) => addChangedValue(newValue, item.id)">
</b-form-input>

...
data() {
  return {
    changedValues: new Map()
  }
},
methods: {
  addChangedValue(newValue, itemId) {
     // itemId is a uniq key, so you wont have duplicates
     this.changedValues.set(itemId, newValue)
  }
}
```

Comment: shall this be in methods or computed? or in justAnotherFunction?

Comment: That's an example, I don't know what you want to do with your updated data! Put that in `methods`, and then do whatever you want with it :)

Comment: it does insert the values to the array but with every keystroke, an object is pushed into the array. how to stop this? i want only for it to enter the array when I click on the save button

Comment: You have to take care yourself you're not duplicating the input (i.e. don't insert two objects from the same item.id). You could use a Map instead for example?
Or use the @change event instead, it should trigger the function when losing the focus on the element.

Comment: could you show me how to not have duplicate items? like to keep the most recent change. I could use @change but if the user decides to enter something again then it would again have duplicate items

Comment: I updated the exemple using a javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Be aware that Maps don't support reactivity in Vue2 out-of-the-box.

Another solution would be to check if the array already contains an object with the same itemId, and not add it if so.

Comment: `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.changedValueArray.map is not a function"` I got this error